# Sound & bluetooth not working on Ubuntu on MacBookPro14,1

Tags: sound, bluetooth, macbook

I recently replaced Mac OS with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on my laptop, and I can't get any sound to work through any of (a) the built-in speakers, (b) headphones connected via the 3.5mm headphone jack, or (c) bluetooth earbuds (bluetooth also doesn't work).

I've tried every solution I've found on askubuntu and ubuntuforums so, to be honest, I'm a bit stumped.

**A (non-exhaustive) list of attempted solutions:**

- force re-loaded alsa
- reinstalled alsa and pulse-audio, and force-reloaded alsa
- started pulseaudio
- re-created .config/pulse directory by renaming and rebooting old directory
- unmuted all things in alsamixer
- added "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" to a new line in alsa configuration  file.
- Installed Cirrus driver

**Here's my machine information:**

Apple Macbook Pro "14,1" (13-inch, 2017, two thunderbolt 3 ports)

**Here's audio, system, and detailed machine info (result of "inxi -SMA"):**

System:
Host: connor-MacBookPro Kernel: 5.15.0-52-generic x86_64
bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME 42.5
Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)

Machine:

Type: Laptop System: Apple product: MacBookPro14,1 v: 1.0
serial:

Mobo: Apple model: Mac-B4831CEBD52A0C4C v: MacBookPro14,1
serial:  UEFI: Apple v: 447.80.3.0.0
date: 12/12/2021

Audio:

Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
driver: snd_hda_intel

Device-2: Broadcom 720p FaceTime HD Camera driver: N/A

Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-52-generic running: yes

Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes

I'm relatively new to Linux, so any and all guidance is appreciated! (I am also open to workaround solutions such as "get a USB-connected speaker, you dumb dumb")

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the Cirrus driver installed for sound:

https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro

ubuntu package install:

```
apt install wget make gcc linux-headers-generic
```

```
git clone https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro.git
cd snd_hda_macbookpro/
#run the following command as root or with sudo
./install.cirrus.driver.sh
reboot
```

Comment: I used that process to download and install the Cirrus driver, and still no luck with sound. I edited the original post to include this attempted solution!